# Unable to load fonts on Ubuntu

Tags: r, cairo

Using R version 4.1.2 on Ubuntu 20.04, I run `hist(10)`. The error says

```
X11 font -adobe-helvetica-%s-%s-*-*-%d-*-*-*-*-*-*-*, face 2 at size 14 could not be loaded
```

I find two things on google. [This thread](https://grokbase.com/t/r/r-help/054wcc3pgj/r-r2-1-0-x11-font-at-size-14-could-not-be-loaded) I can't understand, and [this thread](https://github.com/vaofford/Bio-Deago/issues/26) suggests I build R differently. I did recently build R from source, without the cairo flag recommended by the Bio-Deago github thread, but I have now replaced it with a [binary from Rstudio](https://docs.rstudio.com/resources/install-r/), and the problem persists. Any suggestions? Thanks!

EDIT: the problem only occurs in Rstudio, not when I run R through a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

R gets installed to different places depending on whether you install from source or as a binary: see [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Changing-R-versions-for-the-RStudio-Desktop-IDE), which says:

> For versions of R installed by system package managers (e.g. r-base on Debian or Ubuntu) this will be /usr/bin/R. For versions of R installed from source this will typically (but not always) be /usr/local/bin/R.

Rstudio looks first at `which R`, which in this case is the version from source. I deleted the source version (target of symlink at `which R`). Then when I ran `R` in a terminal, said R is not installed. Then, I followed the Rstudio binary install instructions mentioned in the question. I followed them from the beginning even though I had already installed an Rstudio binary. Now I can run `hist(10)` and get a plot as expected.